# About reshaping numpy array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

```
trainX.size == 43120000
trainX = trainX.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

(1)Does reshape accept a list as an argment instead of a tuple?

(2)Are the following two statements equivalent?

```
trainX = trainX.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
trainX = trainX.reshape((55000, 28, 28, 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the variations:

```
In [1]: np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
Out[1]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [2]: np.arange(12).reshape([3,4])
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [3]: np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

With the `reshape` method, the shape can be arguments, a tuple or a list.  In the `reshape` function is has to be in a list or tuple, to separate them from the first array argument

```
In [4]: np.reshape(np.arange(12), (3,4))
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

and yes, one `-1` can be used.  The total size of the reshape is fixed, so one value can be deduced from the others.

```
In [5]: np.arange(12).reshape(-1,4)
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

The method documentation has this note:

> Unlike the free function `numpy.reshape`, this method on `ndarray` allows
>   the elements of the shape parameter to be passed in as separate arguments.
>   For example, `a.reshape(10, 11)` is equivalent to
>   `a.reshape((10, 11))`.

It's a builtin function, but the signature looks like `x.reshape(*shape)`, and it tries to be flexible as long as the values make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much, hpaulj

Answer (score 0):

From the numpy documentation:

> newshape : int or tuple of ints
>
> The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an
>   integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One shape
>   dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the
>   length of the array and remaining dimensions.

So yes, `-1` for one dimension is fine and your two statements are equivalent. About the tuple requirement,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(9)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> a.reshape([3,3])
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>>
```

So apparently a list is good as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, Thomas Kuhn.