# Why are some functions in numpy are methods of np.ndarray and some are functions?

Tags: numpy

This is kind of a soft question, but I suspect that understanding this will help me (and hopefully others)  to better understand the philosophy of `numpy` (I recently migrated from MATLAB).

Some functions, like `sum`, `max`, `transpose`, `conjugate` etc. are methods of the class `ndarray` so that one can use `arr.sum()`, or `arr.sum(axis=1)` etc.

Most functions, though, are functions of the module `numpy` so you need to call them like `numpy.count_nonzero(arr)`, or `numpy.roll(arr)` etc. Many of there methods only take a single `ndarray` object as input so they can be considered, in terms of design, as properties of the array itself.

What is the logic behind this design choice?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7452

Comment: Often operations are defined as methods of the `ndarray` class.  That fits the OOP paradigm.  And subclasses of `ndarray` may define their own variations.  But `numpy` defines functions as well.  Look at the function code; usually it delegates to the method.  But a function can be used on lists and things that don't have the method.  Again look at the code (I learned to do that in MATLAB in the 1990s).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515725/np-sum-and-np-add-reduce-in-production-what-do-you-use compares `np.sum`, `arr.sum` and another version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558012/about-reshaping-numpy-array - compares `np.reshape` and the method.

Comment: There's a lot of history too.  The current `numpy` is the result of merging several numeric packages a decade ago.  So current code, and especially the API, tries to be compatible with choices made by many developers over a number of years.

Answer (score 1):

I respond to the comments (thanks!):

I initially thought that there was some underlying principle, a fundamental truth. Upon grasping this truth, I conjectured, my understanding of NumPy, of Python and perhaps of life itself would expand and clarify. Alas, it turns out that it's just a patch on a patch on an unplanned patch, without an organizing principle, without a guiding scheme: a mere product of the cosmic stochasticity to which we are all slaves.